# System Cron job not firing

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I am new with WordPress development and using cron job for first time. I am having issue with cron job which is not firing.
Here are all steps i have taken to achieve this.
I have put this line in my wp-config file

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Then i have setup a cron job in my cpanel with this command.

```
wget -q -O - http://mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I have select interval for every 30 minutes.

But now cron job not firing my WordPress function. Here is my code that i am using in functions.php of my theme.

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event'); 
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');
function do_this_hourly() {
wp_mail( 'myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress to test cron');
}
```

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong with this because i am not receiving emails from this function. I will really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: I think the system cron is firing but you are rescheduling the hourly event on every page load. I would remove `>/dev/null 2>&1` from de command to check if the system cron is fired or not and then isolated the problem to the PHP code.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea. I have already remove this from command to test system cron job. Can you see any issue with WordPress function ?

Comment: You are right. I think system cron is not firing. I am using this command with interval of 5 minutes but i am not receiving email from system.
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - http://mydomain/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

Comment: You were right because there was an issue with system cron and now i am using following command and this is working for me.
cd /home/user/public_html; /usr/local/bin/php -q wp-cron.php

Comment: You should write an answer and answer yourself to your question. The accepted answer doesn't include the real fix for your problem.

Comment: I accept this answer because i was thinking that system and WordPress cron are also conflicting because i was using different intervals. So in this answer i have find out a way to set interval for 30 minutes. That is why i accept this.

Comment: That is not correct. Both crons are separated things and can use different intervals. There is no problem at all with a system cron every 30 min and a hourly wp cron event. Otherwise, you should have a system cron for every scheduled event in WordPress, and that is not the case. When the system cron runs, all wp scheduled events that are in queue will be executed, not matter if they are set to 5, 15, 30 min, hourly or daily, if they are ready to run, they will run when wp-cron.php is triggered by the system cron or, if `DISABLE_WP_CRON` is false, by a normal visitor.

Comment: @cybmeta Thank you so much for explaining this very well. I am lot more clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create the interval for 30 mins. Use filter:

```
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules', 999 );
function my_cron_schedules($schedules) {
    $schedules['thirty_min'] = array(
        'interval' => 1800, // Every 30 mins
        'display'  => __( 'Every 30 mins' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
```

Then you need to execute the scheduled job:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'thirty_min', 'your_event_hook' );
```

Then add the action and the callback function:

```
add_action('your_event_hook', 'do_this_hourly');
function do_this_hourly() {
    wp_mail( 'myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress to test cron');
}
```

you need `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in your wp-config.php

Then you can schedule your system cron.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail answer. I am going to try this code for setting interval which is 30 minutes in my case.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry i did not test your code yet. But i figure out the issue. There was problem with system cron and now i am using different command and that is working for me.
cd /home/user/public_html; /usr/local/bin/php -q wp-cron.php

Comment: Now i will test your code and i hope it will work. Then i will accept your answer. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: All the best :)

Comment: **Can you explain why a 30 min interval need to be defined?** The code in the question uses a hourly interval for the wp cron event and 30 min interval for the system cron, that is absolutely valid. Both intervals for system and wp crons don't need to be the same. As @BilalAwan said, the problem he had was with the system cron not firing at all, not the defined interval for the wp cron.